# about subgroup of general linear group

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

Thanks for any comments

Let $G=GL_n(F)$ be general linear group over finite field $F$. Consider two isomorphic  subgeoup $H_1,H_2$ of $G$ such that $H_i\cong GL_k(\bar{F})$, where $\bar{F}$ is an extention of $F$ of prime degree. Is it possible $H_1\cap H_2\neq Z(G)$

Comment: Where does this question come from? What if $H_1=H_2$? It seems that you assert that **any** single subgroup with your property is the center.

Comment: The answer to the question is clearly yes, even if you assume $H_1 \ne H_2$. For example ${\rm GL}(4,2) \cong A_8$ and ${\rm GL}(2,4) \cong A_5 \times C_3$, and there are many possible intersections of pairs of subgroups isomorphic to ${\rm GL}(2,4)$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been answered in a comment.

Comment: @Alex. It is clear that $H_1$ and $h_2$ must be distinct.

Comment: @Professor Holt. Thanks. For other finite fields and other integer $n$, $GL(n,q)$ there exist such a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, as explained in the answer by paul garrett, it is very easy to construct counterexamples.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @DerekHolt's observation, it is easily possible for the centralizer of *part* of a rational representation of a $GL_r(F')$ in $GL_n(F)$ (with $F'$ a finite extension of $F$) to be non-trivial, while the centralizer of the whole image is smaller. Then the conjugate of the image by anything outside the centralizer of the *part* will create a copy of $GL_r(F')$ that intersects the original in a proper subgroup, and that subgroup is at least as large as the centralizer, so properly larger than the center...

Comment: I do not understand your statement. In general $GL_n(F)$ have subgroups isomorphic with $GL_r(F')$ and are distinct. For all $r$ and $n$ and for every pair of  such subgroups, intersection is trivial or not?